# Loop through all R Data Frame columns and drop columns that have correlation factor with target column below a threshold

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a Data Frame called **train**. Its first column is target (0 or 1) and all (many) other columns are numerics. I want to correlate target with all columns and if absolute value of correlation factor is below 0.10, column should be dropped.
I did the following loop:

```
i>=2
for(i in names(train))
{
    if(abs(cor((train[i],train$target))) < 0.10) 
    {
      train[[i]] <- NULL
    }
  else  next
}
```

Then I get the message:

`Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`
What is going on?
PS: I know that same process can be executed with the xapply family of functions but please help with the for loop.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: not actually too sure what is occurring here is this the whole code? Because it looks okay, is it possible to get a more complete code sample/error

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mark, Thomas' response below cleared the issue. There is a kind of typo in my code that I cannot actually locate. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you had typo at condition in `if` statement, where you used `cor((train[i],train$target))`.

It should be `cor(c(train[i],train$target))` or `cor(train[i],train$target)`. Please check out the code below to see if it works

```
i>=2
for(i in names(train))
{
  if(abs(cor(train[i],train$target)) < 0.10) 
  {
    train[[i]] <- NULL
  }
  else  next
}
```

Comment: @EvangelosKatsaros does this answer address the issue?

Comment: Thanks very much. This answer fully addresses the issue.

Comment: @EvangelosKatsaros Great! Then please take this answer accepted if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are working with `mtcars` data. The code below returns the target, say `mpg`, and the features/columns for which the correlation in absolute value is >= 0.1.

```
mtcars[sapply(1: dim(mtcars)[2], function(i) abs(cor(mtcars$mpg, mtcars[,i])) >= 0.1)]
```

Hope this is an alternative to your approach.

Comment: Thanks, it also works. I will keep it as an alternative.